# What is the best way to manage secrets in an Azure IoT Edge?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am moving a containerized application to an Azure IoT Edge device. I used to use docker secrets to manage things like private keys, database passwords etc. Is there a way to manage these secrets from the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Your secrets can be managed as module twin properties from the cloud, and be "encrypted at rest" on your IoT Edge device - see https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/pull/1096 for more info/context.

Comment: But then your complete twin is encrypted ?  Would it be possible to encrypt certain properties of the twin 'at rest'

Comment: Anyone that has access to your moduletwin in the cloud, can read those secrets.  Isn't that a problem ?